# Migrating Nashorn to GraalVM to cache and execute scripts

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm

So I have a java application that uses NashornScriptEngine to create a CompiledScript, where I can then create an Invocable. The compiled script was compiled from a File input which was the js I am trying to run. I then cached this Invocable in a map to later execute. Using it was as simple as

```
import javax.script.Invocable;

public void handleEvent(Event event, Processor processor){
    try {
        Invocable script = cache.get(event);
        if(script != null) {
            script.invokeFunction("run", data);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(event.name());
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) ...
}
```

However, since Nashorn is deprecated, I am trying to switch to GraalVM while achieving the same thing. I saw some GitHub pages that talked about this but it honestly didn't help me. Here are some of the ones I am looking at.

https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/ScriptEngine.md
https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/issues/78

And this is what I found to be the most useful, however it doesn't allow me to invoke at an entry point like my code above could nor could I create an invocable to cache and be called later on.

```
    public void compile(File file){
        try {
            Source source = Source.newBuilder("js", file).build();
            Engine engine = Engine.create();

            Context context = Context.newBuilder("js").engine(engine).option("js.nashorn-compat", "true").build();
            context.eval(source);
            context.close();
        } catch (Exception exception){
            exceptionCaught(exception);
        }
    }
```

Any tips on how I can compile a file (js) to an invocable using GraalVM? Thank you!

Comment: See [Migration Guide from Nashorn to GraalVM JavaScript](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/NashornMigrationGuide.md). No further changes might be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context.eval()` will return a value of type `org.graalvm.polyglot.Value`. When `source` returns a `function`, then this value will answer `canExecute()` with `true` and you can `value.execute(args...)` it repeatedly. See the API of Value: https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Value.html

I see you are setting the `nashorn-compat` option. Please understand this is a backwards-compatibility option that you should best not use. In many scenarios, your code will run perfectly without that option. Please check the [Migration guide](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/NashornMigrationGuide.md) for the cases where something is really not supported by GraalVM JavaScript that is available in Nashorn mode.